# Are global variables safe with Python asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

subj, or what are better ways to access the current state of asynchronous external data?

I have 2 async processes data_gen() and worker().

- data_gen() generates DAT
- worker() acts according to the current status of DAT. Passing it directly or through a queue is no good because they are snapshots of the past statuses of DAT (am I correct here?).

in my case:

1. worker() doesn't need to know the history of DAT, just the current status
2. DAT is changed in 1 place only
3. it is OK for worker() to make a copy of DAT immediately before the action (DAT may change during the execution, but that's not a problem)

```
import asyncio
import random

DAT = 0.0

async def data_gen():
    global DAT
    while True:
        DAT = round(random.random() * 10, 2)
        print(f'data updated to: {DAT}')
        await asyncio.sleep(DAT)


async def worker():
    while True:
        print(f'worker has {DAT}')
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(data_gen(), worker())


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: `worker` only runs while `data_gen` is awaiting `sleep` and `data_gen` only runs while `worker` is awaiting `sleep`, therefore only one of them can access `DAT` at a time.

Answer (score 2):

> Are global variables safe with Python asyncio?

yes, they are; only one coroutine is actually running at once and will until `await`ed

Comment: this seems to be valid for `asyncio` model in general. Still the question remains: is there a more elegant way to access the current state of data from different processes?